Shortcodes do not work in local installation (XAMPP)
I cloned my website to a local installation (XAMPP server).
While everything works properly in live version, in local installation, all shortcodes do not work in local.
I see the [shortcode] in the GUI, but this is not shown in "rendering". Codes are registered via Snippet plugin.
I have Elementor PRO installed, and shortcode do not work both they are placeholder in the gui, to show some content and also if they are registered like "query ID" to filter some elementor queries in post loops.
Can anybody help me?
Ioria

Your question would be best directed to Elementor's support. Third party plugins are off topic here.

this is not a problem of elementor. Like reported, shortcodes do not work everywhere... inside and outside elementor.

If the same code works on your live site the problem is something to do with your local environment, which is also off topic.

It's also difficult for anyone to diagnose or assist with this problem because we genuinely can't see any code.  We don't see what, if any errors there are, we can't see the code that generates the shortcodes, etc.
